# I am trying to insert data using JSP (Eclipse) into database (XAMPP, MySQL)

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets, jdbc, xampp

After submitting the data in my html page, it takes to a blank page and the data was not recorded into my database.My html file name is index.html and jsp file is J3.jsp. I already have the mysqlconnector in reference libraries. The console doesn't show any errors.
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="J3.jsp">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="first_name">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="last_name">
<br>
City name:<br>
<input type="text" name="city_name">
<br>
Email Id:<br>
<input type="email" name="email">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

J3.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>

<%
String first_name=request.getParameter("first_name");
String last_name=request.getParameter("last_name");
String city_name=request.getParameter("city_name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");

try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo11", "root", "");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
out.println("connection successful!");

int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into users(first_name,last_name,city_name,email)values('"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+city_name+"','"+email+"')");
out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.print(e);
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

html output page:
[html output page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oolUL.png)
Submit page:
[submit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyUr9.png)
XAMPP page after submitting:
[XAMPP page after submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NnZS.png)

Checked my port
Checked the database sql file names
checked versions
checked mysql connector
checked apache
replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1

Didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Could be a database commit issue.